# How can I see which processes/programs are sending/recieving data over internet in XP?

Tags: windows, scripting, windows-xp

Is it possible to write a script to see which processes/programs are sending/receiving data over the internet in Windows XP? I have full administrator rights and I want to find a way to monitor data exchange on my machine without installing any additional software.

Comment: There is the [netstat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat) command, this will give you some info `netstat -e -s -p tcp -b`

Comment: Not a script, but Wireshark - http://www.wireshark.org/ will show you whats going over the network

Comment: I've used netpeeker in the past, very useful little tool. Not a script though, but worth a look

Comment: thanks guys for the suggestions i used netstat and came up with only two processes chrome.exe and jqs.exe both of whuch are non malicious but still i have doubts bcoz my network activity shows 730k bytes sent and 6400k bytes recieved these figures mean i should get a good browsing speed but in fact i am not am i missing something? is it possible there may be processes not setected by netstat?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step One:  Windows XP

Open up the Run box by pressing the Windows key and R at the same time.

Put in CMD and press OK. The command prompt window will open up:

Step Two

In your open Command Prompt window, enter the following:

```
netstat -b 5 > activity.txt
```

and hit enter. (Note: to paste something into Command Prompt, you'll need to right click and click paste.)

If you forgot to run the prompt as an administrator (like I did in the screenshots above), just redo step one  You can tell when it's running as administrator because instead of saying C:\Users\Username it says C:\Windows\system32.

If you've pasted the code right, a blinking cursor will... blink.

After a few minutes, press Ctrl+C. That'll stop the command.

```
Now type in command prompt activity.txt to open the log:
```

When you press Enter, your default text editor-probably Notepad-will open:

Now, scroll through the lists.  You'll see that it's mostly your browser-but some times, there are programs like Google Talk's webcam program installed that call home even when you aren't using them.

Now that you've found any and all culprits that are programs accessing the internet (with and without your knowledge), you can either close them from the Task Manager or even uninstall them.

Comment: thanks guys for the suggestions i used netstat and came up with only two processes chrome.exe and jqs.exe both of whuch are non malicious but still i have doubts bcoz my network activity shows 730k bytes sent and 6400k bytes recieved these figures mean i should get a good browsing speed but in fact i am not am i missing something? is it possible there may be processes not setected by netstat?

Comment: you have to clear your temp folder and clear your prefetch folder

Comment: @AdeelMughal Thanks a million bro... you helped a lot